# Entry point not found error using external lib

Tags: visual-studio, qt, qwt

Im using the qwt lib (version 6.1.4) to make plots in c++. I have build the library from the source code by using Qt5.5.1 using msvc2013 compiler. I have done this by loading the qwt.pro file in qt-creator and building it. So far so good and the examples work fine when I load them in Qt.

However I am now trying to include the qwt.dll that was created in the previous steps into an existing project using an older version of Qt (5.4.0). This project uses cmake and visual studio 2013 to build and compile. I have managed to include the header files and link to the qwt.dll in the project, but now I get an error when I use the library:

```
'Entry Point Not Found' in the dynamic link library Qt5Core.dll
```

This qt5core.dll is the one from q5.4.0. Could this error be caused by the fact that I used a newer version of Qt when building the lib? Or is there another reason for this?

And for my understanding what does the error actually mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was indeed the problem that I build the Qwt lib with a different version of Qt then the existing project used. I solved it by adding a Kit to qt that used the other Qt version. Then I used that kit to build qwt in qtcreator and the resulting lib worked like a charm!